# error java.lang.illegalstateexception begin object but was begin array at line 1 column 6 path $ in android studio

Tags: android

## `your text`your text`

```
this is my kotlin code i want to play animal sound 

       binding.animalsoundimg.setOnClickListener {
                var call2=apiinterface.getanimalsound()

                call2.enqueue(object :Callback<animalsound>{
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<animalsound>,
                        response: Response<animalsound>
                    ) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val soundUrl = response.body()?.soundurl

                            if (soundUrl != null) {
                                PlayAnimalSound(soundUrl)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<animalsound>, t: Throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error"+t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                })
            }
        }


    private fun PlayAnimalSound(soundurl:String)
    {
        mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(soundurl)
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mediaPlayer.release()
    }


i have try everything for this thing but icant resolve it so please resolve it`your text`
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: while i clicked on animalsound image that time show error java.lang.illegalstateexception begin object but was begin array at line 1 column 6 path $ in my divice cant play animal sound

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model class "animalsound" and request body from "apiinterface.getanimalsound()" mismatch. Can you share the code of the animalsound class and request response you get.